OpenMP equivalent for OpenACC default(present) clause
Does OpenMP have an equivalent to the default(present) clause from OpenACC?
For instance,
      !$acc parallel loop collapse(2) default(present)
      do j = 1, ny
         do i = 1, nx
            f_xy(i,j) = 0.25_wp*(f(i+1,j+1) - f(i-1,j+1) + f(i-1,j-1) - f(i+1,j-1))
         end do
      end do

can be mapped as,
      !$omp target teams loop collapse(2)
      do j = 1, ny
         do i = 1, nx
            f_xy(i,j) = 0.25_wp*(f(i+1,j+1) - f(i-1,j+1) + f(i-1,j-1) - f(i+1,j-1))
         end do
      end do

but may cause unneccesary data movement.
One can add map(to: f) map(tofrom: f_xy) in the OpenMP directive to limit un-needed data movement, but this isn't really equivalent to the OpenACC clause, which causes a runtime error in case the data is not present on the device. In other words it forces the programmer to make sure the data is in the device address space before-hand.

assert(omp_target_is_present(f, omp_get_default_device())) is probably the closest thing. But you would need to manually check for each array and you cannot test for the whole array at once.
